# negation in query condition yii2

Tags: yii2

How get list without some city in query condition. Something like that

```
joinWith(['address' => function($query){
        $query->orWhere(['order_delivery_address_city' => 'New York']);
        $query->orWhere([ 'order_delivery_address_city' => 'London']);
```

How set negation for this like `!= New York`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query->orWhere(['NOT', ['order_delivery_address_city' => 'New York']]);
```

It is operator form of condition, you might Google more about it,

Instead of 'NOT' you can use operators like < > !=  =     Etc...

Comment: There is error `Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException

Operator 'NOT' requires exactly one operand.`

Comment: @cruim sorry, fixed, check it now